# File transport Error in Biztalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have configured a Receive port and its location. When i run the BizTalk application in i get following error.

> The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "EDIReceiveLocation" with URL "C:\EDIReceive*.txt" to the adapter "FILE". Reason: "File transport does not have read/write privileges for receive location "C:\EDIReceive\". ".

I am receiving a txt file and converting it into an xml in my BizTalk application.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here in the terms of permissions or any other stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service account running the BizTalk host instance that your receive location is associated with must have Full Control permissions on the directory it is polling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good link to take you through which permissions to add and how to add them:

[Biztalk File Permissions](http://geekswithblogs.net/ThomasCanter/archive/2011/01/24/file-system-permission-for-the-biztalk-server-2004-to-2010.aspx)